# ¿Como hago la sumatoria con PYTHON?

Tags: python, python-3.x, bucles, python-3.7

estoy realizando una guia con listas y diccionarios de datos, estoy tratando de resolverla lo mejor posible, para que me quede de referencia, pero por la inexperiencia hay un proceso que necesito hacer y no logro realizarlo, el calculo de los descuentos e impuestos salio bien, pero al tratar de hacerlo en el mismo fragmento de codigo no encuentro mi error, muchas gracias por la ayuda

```
#aca se dec lara el diccionario
Stock={'harina' : 1,
       'azucar' : 1,
       'sal'    : 1,
       'pan frances': 1,
       'jamon'  : 2,
       'queso'  : 3,
       'frijoles':1
      
       }
inventario = list(Stock)
print(Stock)

descuento =  list(Stock )
print (descuento)

producto= Stock.keys()

precio= Stock.values()


def descuento():
  print(*[f'Precio {k}: {v} --> Descuento {k}: {v*0.1}' for k,v in Stock.items()], sep='\n')

def impuesto():
  print(*[f'Precio {k}: {v}  --> Impuesto {k}: {v*0.13} ' for k,v in Stock.items()], sep='\n')

def total_detalle():
  print((*[f'Precio {k}: {v} --> Descuento{k}: {v*0.1} --> Impuesto {k}: {v*0.13} Total a pagar{k}:{(v*0.1)+(v*0.13)+v} ' for k,v in Stock.items()], sep='\n'))

print (total_detalle())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu error radica en 2 cosas:

- Tienes parentesis de mas en el print de `total_detalle`:
- Estas sumando el impuesto y el descuento, deberías restar el descuento.

```py
def total_detalle():
    print(*[
        f'Precio {k}: {v} --> Descuento {k}: {v * 0.1} --> Impuesto {k}: {v * 0.13} Total a pagar {k}:{(v - (v * 0.1)) + (v * 0.13)} '
        for k, v in Stock.items()], sep='\n')
```

Comment: muchas gracias,